# What do you call income and fixed expenses in a single word?

Tags: word-request

Every month we all have got income (e.g. salary, dividends) and fixed expenses (e.g. rent, transport). I am a programmer and in this domain these two entities are the same, except the income is a positive value while the expenses are negative ones.

My question is: what word can be used to characterize both concepts of income and fixed expenses? For example the word animal might mean a dog and a cat as well. And what single word does connote both income and fixed expense?

In other words, what do you call the income and fixed expenses you have got monthly in a single word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Income and expenses are both "accounts".

I'm not sure if that works for you because other things are "accounts" also, like liabilities and capital. If you need a word that INCLUDES both income and expenses, than "accounts" is the most likely word. If you mean a word that includes income and fixed expenses and nothing else ... I don't think there's a generally-accepted term for that.

It's like your "animal" example: dogs and cats are both "animals", but there are other kinds of animals too.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. It looks like the word account works for me. And you were right I needed a word that INCLUDES both income and expenses. I just thought the verb 'to connote' is more appropriate in this case. Thank you twice then.

Answer (score 2):

A little late here, but "cashflow" would fit nicely here and is a term commonly used in business/personal finance.

Cashflow refers to the movement of value (or "flow of cash"), with positive and negative cashflow referring to the value coming into or going out of an account. This includes both literal cash (e.g. coins/notes flowing in and out of a till) and digital cash (e.g. bank transfers and investments).

Note that cashflow is distinct from the currently accepted "account" answer, since cashflow refers specifically to the *movement* of wealth into/out of/between accounts (accounts being the place that cash is stored). .

Answer (score 0):

Household economy = family finance : State of income and expense of one house.

I must do a part time job to help family finance.

Comment: That's two words. OP has specified a single word in his title. And what about adding some source links to on-line dictionaries?

Comment: http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kew000000037&supid=keu000000270

Comment: Sorry, since I can not find one word. In further, I thought that household economy is one word, since there is no one word for household economy.

Comment: Thank you, @HKLee. I am sorry but I wanted more abstract word. "account" given by Jay is fine.

Comment: No problem but that seems a Korean/English dictionary, I mean an English "solo" dictionary like https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/

Comment: Yes. And thank you for introducing a link new to me.